# Reload application in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

Is there any way by which we can reload the whole SAPUI5 application?

When a SAPUI5 app is called, onInit() function is called and we are initializing some settings for view here. Say if some change (like selection of a checkbox in master view) requires the whole application to be reset, can we reload the application and call onInit() function again to correct our initial settings? Is there any trigger mechanism by which we can call onInit() function explicitly?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Regards,
Raja

Comment: When you really want to reset the whole thing you can take a look at [`location.reload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload)

Comment: With databinding a reload shouldn't be necessary. You can update your page depending on the loaded data in a e.g. formatter function.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the need to reload or reset your application, then I would think your app suffers from a major design flaw... This is definitely something I would look into first if I were you!

However, to answer your question, why not move the initialization code into its own function, and call that function from the `onInit()` event handler and whenever you need to reset your app?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. In my application, when Admin users login they can change the settings of other users, when other users page loads I thought it would be better to completely refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you cannot directly use the window global variable in sapui5.

Refer to this page: 
https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/CF/en-US/7d0dba71a2cb45ebb1959daba904ca99.html?q=location%20reload

```js
var myLocation = location;
myLocation.reload();
```

Comment: You can still use it; it will just be flagged as an error by the linter.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use some kind of intercommunication (e.g.: [EventBus](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.EventBus)) between your Controller instances, from the master view notify your Controllers to rerun initialization logic like follows:

1. move you initialization logic to separate functions on each Controller and call this method upon `onInit`
2. in `onInit` subscribe to reinitialize event
3. in you master view add a listener function to the mentioned checkbox selection event, and publish the reinitialize event to notify your Controllers to reinitialize

`Controller.js`:

```
function onInit() {
    this._initialize();
    EventBus.subscribe('reinitialize', this._initialize);
}
funcion _initialize() {
    // init logic
}
```

`MasterController.js`:

```
function onSelectionChange() {
    EventBus.publish('reinitialize');
}
```